# Editext inside the popupwindow shows bad token error in android?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Am using Edit text inside the popup window after am enter the values in edit text it shows some bad token error.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

**My Pop up window Coding.**

```
 inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.image_pop_up, null, true);
                pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                pw.setFocusable(true)
    EditText name = (EditText)popupView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    pw.showAtLocation(activity.findViewById(R.id.order_page_xml), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 15);
```

my log-cat error is

```
05-11 17:44:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1558): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@4169cf30 is not valid; is your activity running?
05-11 17:44:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:513)
05-11 17:44:05.381: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
```

Comment: add some code for popup and edittext.

Comment: @Hardik am add coding of my popup window

Comment: In the inflater1.inflate just set the last param to false.

Comment: @HoanNguyen again am have the same problem.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782250/popupwindow-badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid