# Dialogbox is not working continuously

Tags: android

> E/AndroidRuntime(3966): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41041b40 is not valid; is your activity running?

I got this error while populate dialog box, it working fine when click button in same activity.

If I go back and return to this view it shows this error. But it is working alternative

Comment: Please post related code

Comment: Same error with http://stackoverflow.com/a/8782594/976367

Comment: post full logcat please