# Exception when try to setError() in an editText inside a Popup Window

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow

This is my code:

```
 if(textNomeGiocatore.getText().toString().equals("")){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textNomeGiocatore.getWindowToken(), 0);

                textNomeGiocatore.setError("Nome giocatore necessario");





            }
```

I have an error in the row :

```
 textNomeGiocatore.setError("Nome giocatore necessario");
```

this is the error :

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@426940a8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I try to post delayed the error message without resoult.

Someone Can help me?

Comment: Try this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782250/popupwindow-badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid

Comment: Please, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14488827/1796309

Answer (score 0):

0Please try this:

```
   if(textNomeGiocatore.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null &&  getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        textNomeGiocatore.requestFocus() 
        textNomeGiocatore.setError("Nome giocatore necessario");
    }
```

Comment: Try calling edittext.requestFocus() before calling set error.

Comment: Don't solve the problem.. the problem is that can't put a popup over another popup, or something similar

Comment: Then instead of parent popup use Dialog or Dialog fragment.

Comment: I have to use Dialog instead of PopupWindow?

Comment: I have the same problem, but instead you use dialog, there are another way to get the same result as set error. You can make your own layout to show above/below the edittext. The layout can be just simpl textview with red color or more complex layout depends on your need