# EditText setError not working in PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-popupwindow

I had `popup window` with custom layout which has `edittext`. I'm trying to show error message in `edittext` with `setError` method, but it's giving following exception.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@211ffd68 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:579)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1104)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1008)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:968)
at android.widget.Editor.showError(Editor.java:334)
at android.widget.Editor.setError(Editor.java:355)
at android.widget.TextView.setError(TextView.java:4654)
at android.widget.TextView.setError(TextView.java:4639)
at com.ebusiness.worldofjobs.helpers.HelperEditText.isEmailValid(HelperEditText.java:38)
at com.ebusiness.worldofjobs.activities.LoginActivity$4$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:149)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Popup window:

```
View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(LoginActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_reset_password, null);

EdiText etSmaple = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.etSmample);
Button buttonSample = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSample);

final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 600, 400);

popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

buttonSample.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

             // Here's the exception raising
             etSample.setError("Nothing...");
      }
});

popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: at which line getting issue?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K at `setError("Nothing...")`

Comment: Which android version are you testing this on ?

Comment: @Sushant try this on a previous version like jelly bean.. just for the sake of testing.

Comment: @Sharp Edge sorry dude. but i don't have device or emulator ready.

Comment: I am facing same problem no solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the `setError(String error)`, maybe you added your PopupWindow during the wrong time.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782594/3003823)

Comment: Please elaborate what timing you mean. I tried 2 positions of `showAtLocation()`. Before and after `buttonSample` listener.

Comment: @RockFlower actually i'm doing this code on button click.