# PopupWindow: Editext set error shows bad token error in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have implemented PopupWindow for login in that when I press Login button, I am validating edittext of username and password using setError function. But App is crash with exception **"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window"**

any solution for that?

```
Activity activity;
PopupWindow popupLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity = this;

}


   @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_login:
                    if (popupLogin == null || !popupLogin.isShowing())
                        showLogin();

                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


    private void showLogin() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,
                    null);

            popupLogin = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            popupLogin.setFocusable(true);
            popupLogin.update();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);


            Rect rectangle = new Rect();
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
            int topbar = rectangle.top + toolbar.getHeight();
            edtBroker = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.edit_broker_code);
            edtUname = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
            edtPwd = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.edit_pwd);
            // popupLogin.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);
            popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    popupLogin.dismiss();

                }
            });
            popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (validate()) {
                        popupLogin.dismiss();
                        doLogin(edtBroker.getText().toString().trim(), edtUname.getText().toString().trim(), edtPwd.getText().toString().trim());
                    }
                }
            });

            popupLogin.showAtLocation(toolbar, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, topbar);


        }


 private boolean validate() {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtBroker.getText().toString())) {
            edtBroker.setError(getString(R.string.plz_broker_code));//getting exception here
            edtBroker.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtUname.getText().toString())) {
            edtUname.setError(getString(R.string.plz_enter_username));
            edtUname.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPwd.getText().toString())) {
            edtPwd.setError(getString(R.string.plz_enter_password));
            edtPwd.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (!NetworkStatus.getConnectivityStatus(activity)) {
            CommonUtility.showAlertToast(activity, getString(R.string.check_internet), "");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.app.stockeyez, PID: 29076
>                                                                      android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@33b573b is not valid; is your activity running?
>                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:579)
>                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
>                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                                                                          at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1258)
>                                                                          at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1110)
>                                                                          at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1069)
>                                                                          at android.widget.Editor.showError(Editor.java:445)
>                                                                          at android.widget.Editor.setError(Editor.java:466)
>                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setError(TextView.java:4943)
>                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setError(TextView.java:4928)
>                                                                          at com.app.stockeyez.MainActivity.validate(MainActivity.java:484)
>                                                                          at com.app.stockeyez.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:52)
>                                                                          at com.app.stockeyez.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:278)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: can you share your code where you're getting the error??

Comment: I am getting at error edtBroker.setError(getString(R.string.plz_broker_code));

Comment: any one tell me why down voted my question. I really get this exception

Comment: show the code where you have initialized your popupView

Comment: View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,
                    null); popupLogin = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: This seems to be context error somewhere can you paste the complete exception you're getting

Comment: I posted in question

Comment: ok your activity is finished that's why you're getting the error can you share the flow how are you getting on this popup window??

Comment: I already shown on onOptionsItemSelected method check my whole code in question

Comment: check out this anwer for more clarification : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s
 the reference of your activity you're using is already finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used `applicationContext()` in your activity.

Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, just use `ActivityName.this`.

I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: Dipali ,please check my code what i m doing wrong. I am not using getApplicationContext

Comment: use getResource().getstring() instead of getString()

Comment: tried but still not working. also tiied hard coded message but same error

Comment: Dipali , have you ever implemented setError for popupwindow edittext?

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969026/edittext-seterror-not-working-in-popupwindow?rq=1