# Popup window running as background image in navigation drawer Activity

Tags: android, popup

[Image sample][1]I have popup screen implemented in my navigation drawer activity. Problem is that popup window is showing like background image of activity. What i want to popup come visible in foreground when Activity starts and after 3 seconds dismiss.

Here is my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

    toggle.syncState();    

    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
        View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment));
        // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
        // display the popup in the center
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FragmentMainPage pocetnaFragment = new FragmentMainPage();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment, pocetnaFragment, "1");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Auto magazin");

    ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.LEFT);

    TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);

    Title.setText("Auto magazin");

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view,params);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //show custom title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the default title
}

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    assert drawer != null;

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return;
    }
    else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pritisnite još jednom za izlaz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.podesavanja)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)   {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.pocetna)       {
        FragmentMainPage fragmentMainPage = new FragmentMainPage() ;
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment
               , fragmentMainPage, fragmentMainPage.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
        Title.setText("Auto magazin");
    }
    else if (id == R.id.info)   {
         FragmentMenuPages fragmentMenuPages = new FragmentMenuPages();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment
                , fragmentMenuPages, fragmentMenuPages.getTag()).commit();

        TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
        Title.setText("Info");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("href","http://www.magazinauto.com/category/info/");
        bundle.putString("title", "Info");
        fragmentMenuPages.setArguments(bundle);

    }

    else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
    }
}
```

activity_pop_up:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/popup"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bolt.automagazin.PopUp">
  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView3"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/autojedan" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutZaFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.bolt.automagazin.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
>
```

Comment: That's not your `PopupWindow`. You're inflating `activity_pop_up` directly into `relativeLayoutZaFragment`, underneath the `Fragment` that's eventually transacted on top of it. Then I would imagine you're getting an Exception for the `PopupWindow`, since you're passing it a `View` that's already attached to parent. Change the second argument in the `inflate()` call to `null`, and pass the `(ViewGroup) findViewById(...)` as the first argument in the `showAtLocation()` call.

Comment: Can you show me some example come pls and yes i am getting an Exception?

Comment: Change `View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null);`, and `pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);`.

Comment: When i do like that popup dont show at all :(

Comment: Your `PopupWindow` wasn't ever showing. Check your logcat for an Exception.

Comment: relativeLayoutZaFragment is container where navigaion drawer change fragments.

Comment: OK. Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: No i can try without try/catch block, now when i start nothing happens

Comment: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? in this line   pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: Oh, right, cause you're doing that in `onCreate()`. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4187673, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/8782250.

Comment: Its working now!!,  thanks a lot,  post something , so i can check as correct answer

Comment: OK. Gimme a little bit. I'm on a phone.

Comment: kk np , thanks a lot again,  you save my work;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is not actually your `PopupWindow`. That `inflate()` call is attaching the inflated `View` directly to the `relativeLayoutZaFragment`, and the `Fragment` is being added on top of it. Then, since that `View` is already attached to a parent, the `PopupWindow` is throwing an Exception, and is never shown.

Change the second argument in the `inflate()` call to `null`:

```
View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up, null);
```

And pass the `RelativeLayout` that's in the `Activity` to `showAtLocation()`, instead of the inflated layout:

```
pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment‌​), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Additionally, since you're doing this in `onCreate()`, you'll need to defer showing the `PopupWindow` momentarily, or you'll get that `WindowManager$BadTokenException`. You can do that by putting the `showAtLocation()` call in a `Runnable`, and posting that to a `View`. For example:

```
final View rl = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutZaFragment‌);
rl.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            pw.showAtLocation(rl, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    }
);
```