# How can I get the View received by OnClick without calling it?

Tags: android, view, onclick

The code below works perfect:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            method.show(v);
        }
    });
}
```

However, I need to get `View` without using `onClick`

The code below does not work

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    method.show(button);
}
```

How can I get the same View as passed to `button.onClick`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code looks valid. What do you mean by "the code below does not work". Nothing happens? It throws an exception? Or what?

Comment: what you want we can't understand u? be more specific!!

public void onClick(View v) the argument here is the view that was clicked

Comment: @Brayden I get the following error:

android.view.WindowManager $ BadTokenException: Unable to add window - token null is not valid;

WindowManager not recognized button as a View

Comment: What line do you get that at? You should post the full stack trace.

Comment: can u show your import for Button?

Comment: The method opens a popup on the screen
The error occurs on this line:
PopupWindow.showAtLocation (parentView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xpos, ypos);

View parentView where is the button.
method but only works with onClick (View v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't show a PopupWindow from onCreate().

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4713487/742660)

Comment: Perfect.
was just that.
Runnable in the post, the button was given the attributes of screen position required.

Thank you