# Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android

I want to show a custom popup menu when the user clicks on a floating icon

the floating icon create with service and i have no activity

this is my floating icon code

```
public class copy_actions_service extends Service
{
    ImageView copy_ImageView;
    WindowManager windowManager;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    
    public void onCreate()
    {
        windowManager=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        
        copy_ImageView=new ImageView(this);
        copy_ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        copy_ImageView.setAlpha(245);
        copy_ImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                showCustomPopupMenu();
            }
        });
        
        layoutParams=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        
        layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER;
        layoutParams.x=0;
        layoutParams.y=100;
        
        windowManager.addView(copy_ImageView, layoutParams);

    }
    
    private void showCustomPopupMenu()
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xxact_copy_popupmenu, null);
        
        PopupWindow popupWindow=new PopupWindow();
        popupWindow.setContentView(view);
        popupWindow.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);             
    }
}
```

everything fine but when i click on the float button app stop and this error is shown on logcat :(

```
11-23 02:18:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(3231): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

but I have no activity?

I want to popup menu show after user click on float icon; but popup menu only can show text;

how can I show a popup menu with icons?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, it looks like you used the tutorial from http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics like I did. The problem is that you cannot reliably pass the current activity to the popup window, because you have no control over the current activity. It looks like there might be a unreliable way to get the current activity, but I don't recommend that.

The way I fixed it for my app was to not use the popup window, but instead make my own through the window manager.

```
private void showCustomPopupMenu()
{
    windowManager2 = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xxact_copy_popupmenu, null);
    params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x=0;
    params.y=0;
    windowManager2.addView(view, params);  
}
```

If you want this to look like a popup window, just add a transparent gray view as the background and add a onClickListener to it to remove the view from the windowManager object.

I know this isn't as convenient as a popup, but from my experience, it is the most reliable way.

and don't forget to add permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: how to dismiss this windowmanager when user click outside this view?

Comment: @nidhi use `windowManager2.removeViewImmediate(view);` but make your inflated view a global variable `private View view;`

Comment: this error happens at `windowManager.addView(view, params)` as well - `Caused by android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: it works for Android 8+ but not on Android 6-7

Answer (score 265):

If you're using `getApplicationContext()` as `Context` in **Activity** for the dialog like this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

then use YourActivityName.this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

Comment: The solution above is not relevant. We are looking for context when there is no activity. This solution requires an activity, which is definitely not what we are looking for.

Comment: What if am using a Fragment

Comment: @Flash then you can use requireActivity() in Fragment

Comment: I got this error when trying to build/show an AlertDialog, but I was passing in the appContext for my app/activity. Switching to passing in <MyActivityName>.this fixed the problem immediately.

Comment: If you are wondering why `YourActivityName.this` works but `getApplicationContext()` does not, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967165/5460959

Comment: This works for my case when I try to pop out an AlertDialog. I think this is a Android API internal issue, quite stupid bug right?

Answer (score 31):

This error happens when you are trying to show pop-up window too early, to fix it, give Id to the main layout as `main_layout` and use the below code:

**Java:**

```
 findViewById(R.id.main_layout).post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   }
});
```

**Kotlin:**

```
 main_layout.post {
      popupWindow?.showAtLocation(main_layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
    }
```

Credit to [@kordzik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4713487/6478047)

Comment: bettor to inflate pop menu in onlick listeners .

Comment: I put this at the end of my onCreate and it worked for me to have a tutorial popup when starting for the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass your activity in the constructor

```
 PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(YourActivity.this)
```

Comment: i have NO activity to do this; this code run on an service NOT an activity

Answer (score 10):

If you use another `view` make sure to use `view.getContext()` instead of `this` or `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was inflating a PopupMenu at the very beginning of the activity i.e on onCreate()... I fixed it by putting it in a **Handler**

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PopupMenu popuMenu=new PopupMenu(SplashScreen.this,binding.progressBar);
                popuMenu.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu);
                popuMenu.show();
            }
        },100);
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you coding on **Kotlin** and using **Viewbinding** system.
- Try so: **binding.root.context**.
- It helped me to run AlertDialog.

Answer (score 2):

`PopupWindow` can only be attached to an `Activity`. In your case you are trying to add `PopupWindow` to `service` which is not right.

To solve this problem you can use a blank and transparent `Activity`. On click of floating icon, launch the `Activity` and on `onCreate` of `Activity` show the `PopupWindow`.

On dismiss of `PopupWindow`, you can `finish` the transparent `Activity`.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: i want show popup menu after click on float icon; i can do this but popup menu only show text not icon; how i can make an custom popup menu with icon ?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while trying to show `DatePicker` from `Fragment`.

I changed

```
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(activity!!.applicationContext, ...)
```

to

```
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), ...)
```

and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the windowManager.addView in onCreate

Try to call the `windowManager.addView` after `onWindowFocusChanged` and the status of `hasFoucus` is true.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    //code here
    //that you can add a flag that you can call windowManager.addView now.
}
```

Comment: This solution almost worked for me, in the sense that it did not make crash the application, but the problem is that also when you dismiss the window the `onWindowFocusChanged` is called again thus showing the window repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

In a case that use a dialog in **a class** might be happened, so in **Kotlin** like this:

```
 cContext = activity.applicationContext
  val dialog = Dialog(cContext)
```

**doesn't work** and change it to

```
 showErrorDialog(this) // a method in the activity
 cContext=context
 val dialog = Dialog(cContext)
```

use **direct** Context from the current activity , shortly

```
val dialog = Dialog(activity.applicationContext)
```

change `context` **to**

```
val dialog = Dialog(this)
```