# Why Application not starts by showing Alert Dialog in AOSP

Tags: java, android, android-source

I'm modifying AndroidOS to create a process that brings up a dialog when an application is launched and asks if you want to do a process kill.However, in the code I wrote, the moment I touch the application, it is forced out with an error. Here's the log and source.

I tried to implement it in ActivityThread.java.
The version of AOSP is 8.1.0_r1, and the entire source code before modification is at the following link. The function on line 5429 in the following link applies.[ActivityThread.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r1/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java)

```
09-11 15:55:46.797   643  1025 W WindowManager: Attempted to add application window with unknown token null.  Aborting.
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime: Process: （name of the application）, PID: 4971
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5868)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1738)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6625)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1114)
09-11 15:55:46.798  4971  4971 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5831)
```

---

```
try
{
    String applicationName = ActivityThread.currentProcessName();
    Log.d(TAG, "logdayonnappname:" + applicationName);
    if (applicationName.contains("applications name"))
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(appContext).setTitle("title").setMessage("Hello").show();
    }
    mInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(app);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (!mInstrumentation.onException(app, e))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to create application " + app.getClass().getName()
            + ": " + e.toString(), e);
    }
}
finally {
    // If the app targets < O-MR1, or doesn't change the thread policy
    // during startup, clobber the policy to maintain behavior of b/36951662
    if (data.appInfo.targetSdkVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
            || StrictMode.getThreadPolicy().equals(writesAllowedPolicy)) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(savedPolicy);
    }
}
```

finally i could show dialog by this code but application never starts...why?
I activate alert method in startActivityAsUser.

```
@Override
    public final int startActivityAsUser(IApplicationThread caller, String callingPackage,
            Intent intent, String resolvedType, IBinder resultTo, String resultWho, int requestCode,
            int startFlags, ProfilerInfo profilerInfo, Bundle bOptions, int userId) {
        enforceNotIsolatedCaller("startActivity");
        userId = mUserController.handleIncomingUser(Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid(),
                userId, false, ALLOW_FULL_ONLY, "startActivity", null);
        // TODO: Switch to user app stacks here.
        //PackageManager mManager = getPackageManager();
        //  String heyyo = PackageManager.getNameForUid(userId);
        String heyyo = intent.getPackage();


      Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS:dialooo0");

        **UiHandler ui = new UiHandler();
        ui.alert();**
        Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS:dialooo22");
        String applicationName = ActivityThread.currentProcessName();
        Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS　"+"packagebame:"+heyyo+"callingPackage:"+callingPackage+"//caller:"+caller.toString()+"//resolvedType:"+resolvedType+"//resultWho:"+resultWho);
        return mActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(caller, -1, callingPackage, intent,
                resolvedType, null, null, resultTo, resultWho, requestCode, startFlags,
                profilerInfo, null, null, bOptions, false, userId, null, "startActivityAsUser");
    }
```

alert() is in the class UiHandler

```
public void alert() {
          Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS:dialooo40");
            Looper.prepare();
            Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS:dialooo30");
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG,"logdayonnAMS:dialooo31");
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                    AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(mUiContext).create();
                    d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                    d.setCancelable(false);
                    d.setTitle("dialog");
                    d.setMessage("hey");
                    d.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"dialog shown");
                      }
                    });
                    d.show();

                  }
                });
              }
            }).start();
            Looper.loop();
        }
```

log is here

```
01-18 02:07:46.782   654   894 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest3:com.android.systemui:screenshot
01-18 02:07:46.786  1936  1936 D ActivityThread: logdayonn2android.app.ActivityThread@2b43f5a
01-18 02:07:46.805  1936  1936 I zygote64: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
01-18 02:07:46.819  1936  1936 D LoadedApk: logdayonn:com.android.systemui.SystemUIApplication
01-18 02:07:46.821  1936  1936 D LoadedApk: logdayonnappname:com.android.systemui:screenshot
01-18 02:07:46.828  1936  1936 D ActivityThread: logdayonnappstr:com.android.systemui.SystemUIApplication@a08ff67
01-18 02:07:46.828  1936  1936 D ActivityThread: logdayonnappname:com.android.systemui:screenshot
01-18 02:07:46.828  1936  1936 D ActivityThread: logdayonnAMS:dialoooa
01-18 02:07:46.828  1936  1936 D Instrumentation: logdayonnlast:com.android.systemui.SystemUIApplication@a08ff67
01-18 02:07:46.868  1936  1952 V NuMediaExtractor: setDataSource fd=33 (/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg), offset=0, length=5951
01-18 02:07:46.870   423  1132 D PermissionCache: checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=10026 => granted (323 us)
01-18 02:07:46.873   360   360 W /system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::IMapper/default in either framework or device manifest.
01-18 02:07:46.874  1936  1936 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
01-18 02:07:46.875  1936  1936 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8992.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
01-18 02:07:46.877  1936  1952 V NuMediaExtractor: track of type 'audio/vorbis' does not publish bitrate
01-18 02:07:46.892   548   916 I OMXMaster: makeComponentInstance(OMX.google.vorbis.decoder) in android.hardwar process
01-18 02:07:46.896   548   916 E OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xe9a22e40:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
01-18 02:07:46.923  1936  1957 D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : 8e59954, I0be83d0d26
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 09/22/17
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.21.02.00
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : O17A
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
01-18 02:07:46.982  1936  1957 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : 
01-18 02:07:46.986  1936  1957 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8992.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
01-18 02:07:46.992  1936  1957 I Adreno  : PFP: 0x00000000, ME: 0x00000000
01-18 02:07:46.997   360   360 W /system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.configstore@1.0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs/default in either framework or device manifest.
01-18 02:07:46.998  1936  1957 I zygote64: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
01-18 02:07:47.003  1936  1957 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-18 02:07:47.003  1936  1957 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
01-18 02:07:47.049  1936  1936 I AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST successful; frameCount 20073 -> 20073
01-18 02:07:47.052   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:47.052   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: speaker-protected
01-18 02:07:47.057   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:47.057   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(95: vi-feedback)
01-18 02:07:47.057   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: vi-feedback
01-18 02:07:47.057   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(24) apply and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:47.057   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:47.086   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:47.086   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(1) apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:47.086   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:47.121   536  1916 E msm8974_platform: ramp_speaker_gain: Could not get ctl for mixer cmd - Left Speaker Gain or Right Speaker Gain, not applying speaker gain ramp
01-18 02:07:47.121   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: out_write: retry previous failed cal level set
01-18 02:07:47.227   654   738 I ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{68285b3 u0 com.android.calendar/.alerts.InitAlarmsService}
01-18 02:07:47.297   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=31
01-18 02:07:47.510   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=26
01-18 02:07:47.983   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(1) reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:48.002   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(95: vi-feedback)
01-18 02:07:48.002   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(24) reset and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:48.298   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=32
01-18 02:07:48.462   900   900 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
01-18 02:07:48.510   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=27
01-18 02:07:49.299   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=33
01-18 02:07:49.392   654  1039 I ActivityManager: Killing 1424:com.android.provision/u0a19 (adj 906): empty #17
01-18 02:07:49.392   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1424, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:49.396   900   900 I zygote64: Deoptimizing void com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.NotificationStackScrollLayout.updateContentHeight() due to JIT inline cache
01-18 02:07:49.400   900   900 I zygote64: Deoptimizing void com.android.systemui.statusbar.ExpandableView.updateClipping() due to JIT inline cache
01-18 02:07:49.404   900   900 I zygote64: Deoptimizing void com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.StackScrollAlgorithm.updateClipping(com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.StackScrollState, com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.StackScrollAlgorithm$StackScrollAlgorithmState, com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.AmbientState) due to JIT inline cache
01-18 02:07:49.407   900   900 I zygote64: Deoptimizing void com.android.systemui.statusbar.stack.NotificationStackScrollLayout.updateViewShadows() due to JIT inline cache
01-18 02:07:49.423   654   894 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest2:com.android.provision
01-18 02:07:49.437   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1424, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:49.437   654   740 I zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10019 pid 1424 in 45ms
01-18 02:07:49.459   900   900 I zygote64: Deoptimizing void com.android.systemui.statusbar.ViewTransformationHelper.setVisible(boolean) due to JIT inline cache
01-18 02:07:49.511   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=28
01-18 02:07:50.301   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=34
01-18 02:07:50.466  1003  1656 E ImsSenderRxr: Exception in socket create'java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
01-18 02:07:50.466  1003  1656 I ImsSenderRxr: Couldn't find qmux_radio/rild_ims0socket; retrying after timeout
01-18 02:07:50.512   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=29
01-18 02:07:50.948   654   810 E QCOMPowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.
01-18 02:07:50.949   654   810 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) InputDispatcher identical 2 lines
01-18 02:07:50.949   654   810 E QCOMPowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.
01-18 02:07:51.020   654   915 D ActivityManager: dialog shown
01-18 02:07:51.026   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:51.026   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: speaker-protected
01-18 02:07:51.033   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:51.033   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(95: vi-feedback)
01-18 02:07:51.033   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: vi-feedback
01-18 02:07:51.034   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(24) apply and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:51.034   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:51.069   536  1916 E ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> Not correctly initialized!
01-18 02:07:51.069   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(1) apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:51.069   536  1916 D audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:51.117   536  1916 E msm8974_platform: ramp_speaker_gain: Could not get ctl for mixer cmd - Left Speaker Gain or Right Speaker Gain, not applying speaker gain ramp
01-18 02:07:51.117   536  1916 D audio_hw_primary: out_write: retry previous failed cal level set
01-18 02:07:51.266   654   788 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
01-18 02:07:51.301   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=35
01-18 02:07:51.514   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=30
01-18 02:07:51.631   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(1) reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-18 02:07:51.647   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(95: vi-feedback)
01-18 02:07:51.647   536   605 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(24) reset and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
01-18 02:07:52.303   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=36
01-18 02:07:52.516   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=31
01-18 02:07:52.574   654   810 E QCOMPowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.
01-18 02:07:52.575   654   810 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) InputDispatcher identical 2 lines
01-18 02:07:52.575   654   810 E QCOMPowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.
01-18 02:07:53.305   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=37
01-18 02:07:53.518   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=32
01-18 02:07:54.307   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=38
01-18 02:07:54.468  1003  1656 E ImsSenderRxr: Exception in socket create'java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
01-18 02:07:54.469  1003  1656 I ImsSenderRxr: Couldn't find qmux_radio/rild_ims0socket; retrying after timeout
01-18 02:07:54.519   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=33
01-18 02:07:55.309   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=39
01-18 02:07:55.521   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=34
01-18 02:07:55.894   900  1060 I vol.Events: writeEvent level_changed STREAM_MUSIC 3
01-18 02:07:56.311   533   533 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [533]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=40
01-18 02:07:56.522   549   584 E QC-QMI  : qmi_client [549]: unable to connect to server, errno=[2:No such file or directory], attempt=35
01-18 02:07:56.956   654   682 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest1:com.android.keychain
01-18 02:07:56.956   654   682 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1968:com.android.keychain/1000 for service com.android.keychain/.KeyChainService
01-18 02:07:57.001   654   932 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest3:com.android.keychain
01-18 02:07:57.008   654   932 I ActivityManager: Killing 1069:com.android.settings/1000 (adj 906): empty #17
01-18 02:07:57.012   654   932 I ActivityManager: Killing 1599:com.android.quicksearchbox/u0a57 (adj 906): empty #18
01-18 02:07:57.012   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1069, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.015  1968  1968 D ActivityThread: logdayonn2android.app.ActivityThread@2b43f5a
01-18 02:07:57.037  1968  1968 I zygote64: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
01-18 02:07:57.053  1968  1968 D LoadedApk: logdayonn:null
01-18 02:07:57.055  1968  1968 D LoadedApk: logdayonnappname:com.android.keychain
01-18 02:07:57.055  1968  1968 D ActivityThread: logdayonnappstr:android.app.Application@a08ff67
01-18 02:07:57.055  1968  1968 D ActivityThread: logdayonnappname:com.android.keychain
01-18 02:07:57.055  1968  1968 D ActivityThread: logdayonnAMS:dialoooa
01-18 02:07:57.055  1968  1968 D Instrumentation: logdayonnlast:android.app.Application@a08ff67
01-18 02:07:57.057   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1069, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.059   654  1406 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest2:com.android.settings
01-18 02:07:57.065   654   747 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 1069
01-18 02:07:57.065   654   682 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest2:com.android.quicksearchbox
01-18 02:07:57.083   654   682 I ActivityManager: Killing 1622:android.process.acore/u0a2 (adj 906): empty #17
01-18 02:07:57.100   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1069, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.101   654   740 I zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 1069 in 88ms
01-18 02:07:57.101   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1599, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.101   654   740 I zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10057 pid 1599 in 0ms
01-18 02:07:57.101   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1622, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.114   654   932 D ActivityManager: logdayonntest2:android.process.acore
01-18 02:07:57.147   654   740 W zygote64: kill(-1622, 9) failed: No such process
01-18 02:07:57.147   654   740 I zygote64: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10002 pid 1622 in 45ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is "Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?" Which means you are trying to add a window to an activity which is not running currently. You can refer solution suggested on [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087983/unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid-is-your-activity-running/)

Also you are using appContext while creating the dialog, You need to add that particular activity's context instead of appContext.

Instead of using

```
if(applicationName.contains("applications name")){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(appContext).setTitle("title").setMessage("Hello").show();
    }
```

You need to use

```
if(applicationName.contains("applications name")){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title").setMessage("Hello").show();
    }
```

I hope this will work for you.
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

ActivityThread.java is running in app's process. You'd better do hook in ActivityManagerService#startActivityAsUser.

Comment: I have to get application's name but app.processName is not usable in startActivityAsUser... what should i do?

Comment: ActivityThread.currentProcessName() is also null...

Comment: If  go through startActivityAsUser,  you will find that it will first query which package can handle the intent, so it will be the proper place to do the hook, and you will get the package name there.

Comment: I think I cant get context for dialog... please help me                                                           
01-08 01:59:21.903   668   712 E ActivityManager: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: Finally i could show dialog.
but application never starts...why?