# Android set error message inside popup window

Tags: android, exception

When using set error message inside popup window,application is crashing.

> Error:- android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
>   window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c912902 is not valid; is
>   your activity running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this error usually occur if Your activity will be destroyed. It´s possible that another issue stops the activity and in case of overlap, it crashs twice beacuse of a dialog that is shown without an existing activity. But there are also other possible issues. Maybe it helps if You put Your popup show method inside an if/else statement like: if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())

Answer (score 0):

Adding a code along with your question would have been a better idea. However,
You might be showing your popup too early. You may post a delayed runnable for showatlocation in Onresume , Give it a try.

Else go through this post which seems to have the same problem answered [Unable to add window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187673/problems-creating-a-popup-window-in-android-activity)

Further you can also refer [this](http://blackriver.to/2012/08/android-annoying-exception-unable-to-add-window-is-your-activity-running/) link to solve your problem